# listen to Firestore's onSnapshot while app is not running

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, background-task

I want my app to be able to listen to `onSnapshot`  while it is in background , I know that I can use `background task` for this by I don't know how to set it up .

btw I'm trying to implment this so that my app can  push a notification whenever a new doc is received while app is in the background  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most mobile operating systems severely limit what the app can do while it is backgrounded. Keeping an active connection open to a server is one of those things that has never been allowed on iOS, and has gotten more restrictive with recent Android versions.

The better approach is to run the code that detects a relevant change on a server, and then use Firebase Cloud Messaging (or APNS directly if you're only targeting iOS) to send a notification to the user. When they they tap on that notification, your app is started and you can load the data from Firestore.

If you don't want to run your own server, Cloud Functions is a common alternative for this, as it has built in triggers that respond to changes in Firestore. For an example of this exact scenario, see the documentation on [notify users when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).

Comment: thanks I thought cloud messaging was used only for sending messages to clients such as updates or news ... , so I see what you mean I can literally detect changes then send messages based on that